# Spinner OnItemClickListener

Tags: android

```
public class GraphFrame extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    Integer hoodSelector = 27;
    ArrayList<HoodData> hoodDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> hoodList = new ArrayList<>();
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph,
                container, false);
        setHoodId(34);


        //API Request for all the hoods


        getDataFromApi((GraphView) view.findViewById(R.id.graph));
        getDataForSpinner((Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner));
        return view;
    }

    public void setHoodId(Integer hood){
        hoodSelector = hood;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
    public void getDataFromApi(final GraphView graph) {
        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String url= "http://test.dontstealmywag.ga/api/damage_or_theft_car_wijk.php?hood_id=" + hoodSelector;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Do something with the response
                        try{
                            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray values=o.getJSONArray("");
                            for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = values.getJSONObject(i);
                                hoodDataList.add(new HoodData(jsonObject.getDouble("percentage"), jsonObject.getInt("hood_id"), jsonObject.getInt("year"), jsonObject.getString("hood_name")));
                            }

                        }  catch (JSONException ex){}
                        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
                                new DataPoint(1, hoodDataList.get(0).getPercentage()),
                                new DataPoint(2, hoodDataList.get(1).getPercentage()),
                                new DataPoint(3, hoodDataList.get(2).getPercentage()),
                                new DataPoint(4, hoodDataList.get(3).getPercentage()),
                                new DataPoint(5, hoodDataList.get(4).getPercentage())
                                //new DataPoint(12, 0)
                        });
                        graph.setTitle("Wijk " + hoodSelector + " - " + hoodDataList.get(0).getHood_name());
                        StaticLabelsFormatter staticLabelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graph);

                        // set manual x bounds
                        staticLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(new String[] {"2006", "2007","2008","2009","2011"});
                        //creates custom x-axis
                        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(staticLabelsFormatter);
                        //set nice background color :)
                        series.setDrawBackground(true);
                        //shows points at datapoints
                        series.setDrawDataPoints(true);
                        //size of the points
                        series.setDataPointsRadius(10.0f);
                        graph.addSeries(series);



                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Handle error
                    }
                });


        rq.add(stringRequest);
    }
    public void getDataForSpinner(final Spinner spinner){
        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String url= "http://test.dontstealmywag.ga/api/damage_or_theft_car_wijk.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Do something with the response
                        try{
                            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray values=o.getJSONArray("");
                            for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = values.getJSONObject(i);
                                if (!hoodList.contains(jsonObject.getString("hood_name"))) {
                                    hoodList.add(jsonObject.getString("hood_name"));
                                }
                            }
                        }  catch (JSONException ex){}
                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(spinner.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hoodList);
                        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                        spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                setHoodId(27);
                            }
                        });


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Handle error
                    }
                });


        rq.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

I want to set my hood_id to another value when I click one item inside the Spinner so I could create different graphs per hood, but somehow this doesn't work. Could anyone put me in the right direction or help me fixing this.

Comment: You need to add array in string xml file

Comment: Show us your string xml file

Comment: @Lokesh Sorry I've hitted enter way to fast. The question wasn't correct. Now it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` on the spinner. Instead of

```
spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                setHoodId(27);
                            }
                        });
```

try

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(GraphFrame.this);
```

Comment: Now my graphs aren't drawn. This is probably because the OnItemSelectedListener method isn't called inside my API call. Any way to fix this